# Java/Android: SealedObject throws StreamCorruptedException

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography

I want to encrypt and decrypt Objects which where previously encrypted in a SealedObject with a generated AES key, which is persisted and encrypted as well in a SealedObject but with RSA.

### Code

Stack is part of my project library and Serializable. Every Object named xxxStack is a subclass of Stack.

#### Excerpt from chat.protocol.secure.CryptoStack

Relevant attributes

```
// encrypted Object
private SealedObject stack;
// cache for the Object
private transient Stack stackCache;

// encrypted AES key
private SealedObject key;
// cache for AES key which is used to encrypt and decrypt the Object
private transient SecretKey keyCache;
```

Method for encrypting the cached Object (stackCache) with an unique AES key which is then encrypted with a public RSA key and saved in stack

```
public void encrypt(Cipher c0) throws IllegalBlockSizeException, IOException{
    /*
     * Creates unique AES key for encrypting the Object
     */
    KeyGenerator keyGen = null;
    try {
        keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    keyGen.init(256);
    keyCache = keyGen.generateKey();

    /*
     * Creating AES Cipher for encryption
     */
    Cipher c1 = null;
    try {
        c1 = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        c1.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyCache);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    /*
     * Encrypts Object
     */
    stack = new SealedObject(stackCache, c1);
    /*
     * Encrypts AES key with a Cipher given as argument (intended to be a public RSA key initialized Cipher)
     */
    key = new SealedObject(keyCache, c0);
}
```

Method for decrypting the encrypted AES key to decrypt the saved Object with it. The argument c is intended to be an RSA private key initialized Cipher.

```
public void decrypt(Cipher c) throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, IOException{

    //decrypting the AES key (CryptoStack.java:110)
    keyCache = (SecretKey) key.getObject(c);

    //generating Cipher for decryption
    Cipher c1 = null;
    try {
        c1 = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        c1.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyCache);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //decrypting Object with previous generated Cipher
    stackCache = (Stack) stack.getObject(c1);
}
```

#### Excerpt from chat.client.core.Client

Relevant attributes

```
//Connection to the Server
private Socket socket;

//InputStream
private ObjectInputStream oin;

//Listener for incoming data
private IncomingStackListener l;

//HashMap for caching PublicKeys
private ConcurrentHashMap<String, PublicKey> publicKeyCache = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, PublicKey>();
```

Thread waiting for incoming data which is being decrypted an given to the Listener.

```
public void run() {
    Stack stack = null;
    while (!isInterrupted()) {
        try {
            stack = (Stack) oin.readObject();

            /*Irrelevant code removed*/

            // Detect and decrypt encrypted data
            if (stack.getType().equals(StackType.ENCRYPTED)) {

                Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
                c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, me.getPrivateKey());
                //following: Client.java:75
                ((CryptoStack) stack).decrypt(c);
                stack = ((CryptoStack) stack).getCache();

            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException
                | NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException
                | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException
                | BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        l.onStackEntry(stack);
    }
}
```

### The Problem

On a standard JVM enviroment everything works fine.
But using this code (which is part of my project library) in an Android App the decryption of the unique key stored in SealedObject key fails with following LogCat Output:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:2070)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
javax.crypto.SealedObject.getObject(SealedObject.java:220)
chat.protocol.secure.CryptoStack.decrypt(CryptoStack.java:110)
chat.client.core.Client.run(Client.java:75)
```

How to get this working on Android as well?
If needed for solution I'm ready to provide more code

Comment: I would really not go for object serialization for a chat client (or any other communication within a not-homogeneous environment). Differences between versions and implementations would become a major concern.

Comment: I know that this wasn't the best idea, but since it does not need to be perfectly running in a real scenario anyways and it's only for a little school project I decided to go this way.
But it's irrelevant anyway since atm I only want this working correctly like it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured out what the problem was.
When using encryption cross-platform between Android and other "PC" platforms make sure that you specify algorithm, mode AND padding (e.g. "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding") because specifying only the algorithm (like "AES") seems to cause misunderstandings.